# Mysqli affected rows for INSERT IGNORE returning zero

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a large INSERT IGNORE statement with lots of rows of data (3600 on average) an example below (Tms is a unique field - data comes from a PLC and occasionally it sends the data through twice hence the IGNORE):

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `testing ` (`Tms`, `Freq`) VALUES (‘2019-12-06 22.55.01.000000’, ‘50.01’), (‘2019-12-06 22.55.02.000000’, ‘50.07’), (‘2019-12-06 22.55.03.000000’, ‘50.11’);";
$db_insert = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$db_insert->execute();
```

I have tried using:

```
$rows = $db_insert->affected_rows;
```

And also:

```
$rows = $mysqli->affected_rows;
```

And also:

```
$rows = mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);
```

And also:

```
$rows = mysqli_affected_rows($db_insert);
```

$rows is always zero, even when all 3600 entries have been inserted into the DB.
I have the count of the number of entries that are in the insert command, I want to check to make sure all of them have been inserted into the DB and take action when they haven’t been.

Comment: Are you want to just make sure if the last query executed successfully or not?

Comment: if you want to just make sure that query executed successfully do as follow
**
if($mysqli->sqlstate == '0000'){
   // query ran successfully 
}else{
// something went wrong in insert ignore query.
}
**

Comment: I will give that a try. There are occasions where ‘$db_insert’ is TRUE, the PHP script reports adding 3600 entries to the SQL statement, but on querying the DB there are no entries or a few hundred. So I was hoping to compare the numbers sent for insert with the numbers actually inserted.

Comment: I don't understand why you need that function? If the insert failed you should get an exception (see above link). If it was successful, then there hardly ever is a reason you would like to know how many rows were inserted.

Comment: You may get table row count before insert ignore and table row count after insert ognore, difference of these two will give you inserted row count. You may need to use locking to avoid simulation request.

Comment: Dharman as stated, I am on occasion getting some of the entries, but not all of them that were being sent for insert with the statement. I have two devices reporting 1 second logs every hour. 172800 entries a day, missing a few entries means finding the missing ones and resubmitting the 1 hour log again - I wanted a warning when some are missed making it possible to resubmit the hour log which failed to load the first time round.

Comment: jagad89 I will take a look at locking and comparing - the DB isn’t busy so this shouldn’t cause any issues, thank-you for the pointer!